# Будет ли уместно так хранить данные в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Вот у меня есть таблица, в ней поля [id, create_date, images, ...].

Идея такова, я, что бы не создавать ещё одну таблицу, просто буду хранить картинки в поле таблицы **images**, в виде *JSON* `{"1": "www.site.ru/img1.jpg", ...}`.

Вопрос, это нормально? или всё же сделать отдельную таблицу? влияет ли это на скорость и безопасность? Спасибо.

*MySql + PhP*

Comment: А удалять картинку как будете? А обновлять?

Comment: Можно на postgress перейти. там подобные штуки - нормально. Более того, там даже есть апи для доступа к отдельным полям json-поля.

Comment: Легко, при редактировании картинок, мы загружаем с сервера этот JSON объект, и редактируя картинки в панели, мы будем изменять этот объект, а когда сохранять, то просто его отравляем в БД.

Comment: Вот и скажите - зачем вы себе придумываете лишние операции? Перегнать из джсона, сохранить в джсон. Для чего?

Comment: И да - если вам неинтересны реляционные структуры - то может попробовать NoSQL?

Comment: `мы загружаем с сервера этот JSON объект, и редактируя картинки в панели, мы будем изменять этот объект, а когда сохранять, то просто его отравляем в БД.` - допустим у вас миллион картинок, или 10 миллионов. Как вы думает сколько вы будете этот json грузить и парсить?) а потом еще и обратно сбирать

Comment: Если обрабатываться они будут только в php то ещё проще просто массив серилизовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну, если по-феншую - то конечно же так делать нельзя.

но, как правило, даже когда совсем нельзя - иногда все-таки можно... любые правила можно (и нужно) иногда нарушать, но делать это надо **осознанно**... осознанное отступление отправил от неосознанного отличается четким пониманием положительных и отрицательных последствий.

Предлагаю небольшой селф-тест, набор вопросов, который стоит задать самому себе, прежде чем внедрить решение "через ж...":

- я мог бы (умею ли) сделать по-нормальному? я это умею, и могу сделать примерно с теми же усилиями, что и не-по-нормальному?
- отступление от правил дает мне какую-то выгоду?
- серьезно? кроме лени и желания быть "не как все" - есть какие-то серьезные объективные причины сделать не-по-уму?
- отступление от правил создает какие-то проблемы/минусы?
- я уверен, что осознаю ВСЕ возможные отрицательные последствия отступления от правил?
- действительно уверен?
- и эти плюсы перевешивают минусы как минимум на порядок?

если на все вопросы ответили "да" - то может быть и есть смысл отступить от правил... а может, все-таки, и нет...

но если хотя бы на один вопрос ответили хотя бы "наверное" - то см. самое первое предложение в моем ответе :)

---

ну а по вашему случаю, ключевой вопрос состоит в том, сколько картинок (в среднем по таблице) будет на один сайт? И сколько ожидается обновлений (добавили/удалили/изменили картинку) на 100 чтений?

Если у вас там 100500 сайтов, но всего лишь 2 из них имеет по 2 картинки, и они будут пол-раза обнволяться на 100500 чтений - да флаг вам в руки, хоть JSON, хоть бинарный формат изобретайте, кроме ненависти тех, кому это поддерживать, других неприятностей вы, скорее всего, не поимеете...

Ну а если кол-во картинок примерно равно или больше кол-ву сайтов, на один сайт ожидается дофига картинок, обновляться они будут регулярно... то не изобретайте себе проблемы и заведите таблицу.

Answer (score 6):

Это не нормально. В прямом и переносном смысле ([нормализация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)). Через время, когда картинок наберется достаточное количество, Вы будете рвать на себе волосы: "как это поддерживать?"

Ваша задача - облегчить себе задачу. Эти конвертации - потенциальное место для багов. Со структурированными изначально данными будет проще, а если Вы используете ORM - так вообще вопрос должен отпасть.